# Is there a multivariate t distribution with four parameters?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

In the appendix A.2 of this [paper](http://ideas.repec.org/p/hhs/rbnkwp/0191.html) (page 27), a multivariate t distribution with 4 parameters is mentioned. This definition is a little different from what I have seen. for example see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_Student_distribution) .

There is this $S^{*}$ which is used instead of $v$ (degree of freedom) in the nominator and the bracket. Is it a generalization of multivariate t distribution?

**Edit**
The distribution in the paper is the following:
$$p(x|\mu,\Sigma,\nu,S^{*})=\frac{\Gamma\left[(\nu+p)/2\right]}
{\Gamma(\nu/2)
(S^{*})^{-\frac{v}{2}}
\pi^{p/2}
\left|{\Sigma}\right|^{1/2}}
\left[(S^{*})+({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^T{\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})\right]^{-(\nu+p)/2}$$

in which $x:p\times 1$. What is the role of $S^{*}$ here? This does not enter the standard definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can see the definition give in S. Kotz, S. Nadarajah Multivariate $t$-Distributions and Their Applications:

"
...

A $p$-dimensional random vector $\vec{X}= (X_i\ldots X_p)$ is said to have the $p$-variate $t$-distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu$, mean vector $\mu$, and correlation matrix $R$ (and with $\Sigma$ denoting the corresponding covariance matrix) if its joint probability density function (pdf) is given by
$$\frac{\Gamma\left[(\nu+p)/2\right]}{\Gamma(\nu/2)\nu^{p/2}\pi^{p/2}\left|{R}\right|^{1/2}}\left[1+\frac{1}{\nu}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^T{R}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})\right]^{-(\nu+p)/2}$$..."

So in you case you have an $l$-variate $t$-distribution with mean vector $\tilde{Z}\gamma_1$, with $S^{*}$ degrees of freedom and correlation matrix $\mathrm I +\tilde{Z}(M^*\!)\tilde{Z'}$.

Well, you have
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+l}{2}\right)(S^*)^{\frac{m}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})
\pi^{\frac{l}{2}} \left|\mathrm I +\tilde{Z}(M^*\!)\tilde{Z'}\right|^{1/2}}
\left[(S^{*})+(\tilde{{\mathbf y}}-\tilde{Z}\gamma_1)^T{\left|\mathrm I +\tilde{Z}(M^*\!)\tilde{Z'}\right|}^{-1}(\tilde{{\mathbf y}}-\tilde{Z}\gamma_1)\right]^{-\frac{m+l}{2}}$$
So if we pull $S^*$ out of the brackets and normalize the correlation matrix by setting $\Sigma=\frac{\left|\mathrm I +\tilde{Z}(M^*\!)\tilde{Z'}\right|S^*}{m}$ one will obtain

$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+l}{2}\right)\left(\frac{m}{S^*}\right)^{\frac{l-1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})
\pi^{\frac{l}{2}} m^{\frac{l}{2}}\left|\Sigma\right|^{1/2}}
\left[1+\frac{1}{m}(\tilde{{\mathbf y}}-\tilde{Z}\gamma_1)^T{\left|\Sigma\right|}^{-1}(\tilde{{\mathbf y}}-\tilde{Z}\gamma_1)\right]^{-\frac{m+l}{2}}$$
Then up to the scaling factor (normalizing constant) of $\left(\frac{m}{S^*}\right)^{\frac{l-1}{2}}$ which does not depend on observations you will get the $l$-variate $t$-distribution with $m$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is with the $S^{*}$ in that papers definition. Please see my edit.

Comment: Check for the update. Is this what you were seeking?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Of course, I think it should be $\Sigma=\frac{\left|\mathrm I +\tilde{Z}(M^*\!)\tilde{Z'}\right|S^*}{m}$ and the scaling factor is $\left(\frac{m}{S^{*}}\right)^{\frac{l-1}{2}}$. I have one more question and I will be grateful if you answer. What is the role of this scaling factor?

Comment: Well, yes, you are right, it's my inadvertence. Hard to do it without a pen, just online. :) I've corrected it. About scaling factor. You see that in bayesian inference you have to perform normalization of the posterior pdf of the parameter under estimation. So if you perfrom it in your case you probably get this scaling factor and after dividing by this normalization constant you will get rid of it.